# PHP Loop through arrays consecutively based on value

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I'm having a looping mind-breaking issue which I can't seem to solve myself. Currently working on saving a form input in a webshop. The data:

```
"personalisation" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "embroidery"
    1 => "printing"
    2 => "embroidery"
  ]
 "repeat" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "true"
    1 => "true"
  ]
"selectedColors" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "3"
  ]
```

The problem which I have here: I need to loop through the personalisation array to add to my DB. With the embroidery, the repeat value is linked and for the printing the selectedColors is linked. How can I loop through the personlisation array and match the values from the other array?

Comment: Seems like a bad design of form inputs.

Comment: Agree. Unfortunately I can't change the form input :-(

Comment: is it the key from `personalization` representing value in `selectedColors` ?

Comment: @Leorent No value in selectedColors is the color id

Comment: So the 0 and 1 in `repeat` correspond to what exactly? The first and second occurrence of `embroidery` in personalisation? And same for printing/selectedColors? Then it would probably make the most sense that you “split” personalisation into two sub-arrays by value first, [0=>embroidery,1=>embroidery] and [0=>printing], so that you can then use those “new” indexes to access the corresponding values in repeat/ selectedColors, respectively …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't recommend designing forms like this, you're basically just sending a jumbled mess to your backend with no association.

You can "correct" the association by filtering the personalisation array and reindexing it so the keys match the other arrays.

```
$embroderies = array_values(array_filter($array['personalisation'], function($item) {
   return $item === 'embroidery';
}));

foreach($emborderies as $key => $value) {
    // get value from $array['repeat'][$key];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any other way than to use a helper array for example.

It could be
    array('embroidery' => 'repeat', 'printing' => 'selectedColors')

And you start looping through personalization, depending on the value you use it as a key in the helper array, then finally get the wanted value from the array.

1st iteration: 0/embroidery -> embroidery/repeat -> repeat/true

2nd iteration: 1/printing -> printing/selectedColors -> selectedColors/
...